# Box2D Body is not removed immediately (LibGDX Android)

Tags: android, box2d, libgdx, physics, game-engine

I am learning libGDX on android. I am trying to remove body from world after collision. But, some times, bodies are not removed immediately, it takes 2-3 seconds to remove properly.

```
    private void deleteDeadBodies(){
    Iterator<Body> i = world.getBodies();
    Body node=i.next();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Body oBj=node;
        node=i.next();
        if(oBj.getUserData() == Constants.BodyType.DESTROY){     
            removeBodySafely(oBj);
        }
    }
}

private void removeBodySafely(Body body) {
    final ArrayList<JointEdge> list = body.getJointList();
    while (list.size() > 0) {
        world.destroyJoint(list.get(0).joint);
    }
    world.destroyBody(body);
}
```

I am calling deleteDeadBodies() after world step functions.
My world step parameters are,

```
    public static final float BOX_STEP = 1/80f;
public static final int  BOX_VELOCITY_ITERATIONS = 6;
public static final int BOX_POSITION_ITERATIONS = 2;
```

Can any body help me out here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your concern .. I have solved the problem .. and, game was not freezing, just bodies dont get removed.
I solved it like that,
I made an array (deadBodies ) of bodies which are need to be deleted, add the bodies in to that array on postSolve method of contact listener.

Then I re-construct my code like this,

```
       public void update(float delta , float accelX){
      accumulator += delta;
      while(accumulator>Constants.BOX_STEP){
         world.step(Constants.BOX_STEP,Constants.BOX_VELOCITY_ITERATIONS,Constants.BOX_POSITION_ITERATIONS);         
         accumulator -= Constants.BOX_STEP;
      }
      removeDeadBodies();
        }
   private void removeDeadBodies(){
      for(int i = 0; i<deadBodies.size();i++){
         Body body = deadBodies.get(i);
         if(!world.isLocked() && body != null){
            removeBodySafely(body);
            deadBodies.remove(body);
         }
      }
   }

   private void removeBodySafely(Body body) {
      final Array<JointEdge> list = body.getJointList();
      while (list.size > 0) {
         world.destroyJoint(list.get(0).joint);
      }
      world.destroyBody(body);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code looks a little strange...

Why don't you do like this:

```
  Iterator<Body> i = world.getBodies();
    Body node;

    while (i.hasNext()) {
        node=i.next();
        if(node.getUserData() == Constants.BodyType.DESTROY){     
            removeBodySafely(node);
        }
    }
```

Also, this looks strange:

```
  world.destroyJoint(list.get(0).joint);
```

Are you sure you want to retrieve the same item several times in the while loop?

Try this:

```
 final ArrayList<JointEdge> list = body.getJointList();
    for(JointEdge edge : list)
        world.destroyJoint(edge.joint);
    }
```